# m4 command not found after manual install

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, m4

Just finished installing ubuntu 16.04.1 desktop version.  Now I am trying to install m4.  So far installed m4 as follows.

1. Downloaded m4-1.4.18.tar.gz
2. tar -xvzf m4-1.4.18.tar.gz
3. cd m4-1.4.18
4. ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/m4
5. make
6. sudo make install

Now when I type:

```
m4 --version
```

It still says:

```
The program 'm4' is currently not installed....
```

What step am I missing?

**Note**: I do not have internet access on this machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally on Ubuntu you'd just do `apt-get install m4` to install `m4` (which assumes you have an Internet connection), or download [the `m4` package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/m4) and copy it across.

The way you've gone about things, `m4` has been installed in `/usr/local/m4/bin`, so you need to run `/usr/local/m4/bin/m4` or add `/usr/local/m4/bin` to your `PATH`. Alternatively, you can re-install, using

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

which will install `m4` to `/usr/local/bin`, which should already be on your `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks, running PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/m4/bin did it!  Am I going about this the right way?  Seems manually downloading the *.tar.gz file is not the right way?  I see the update.  How would I uninstall it first correctly?

Comment: Manually downloading the tarball isn't the best way, no, but it's not wrong either. `sudo make uninstall` in your current source tree will uninstall `m4`, or you can simply delete `/usr/local/m4`.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfect.  I think I am back on track now.  Much appreciated Steve.

Comment: I would avoid using `/usr/local` at all if it's used by a package manager. Much safer to use e.g. `/opt` or `/sw` or `$HOME/local`. See also [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/).

Comment: @Kusalananda `/usr/local` is never used by a package manager. The whole point of `/usr/local` is to install local software; that's why `./configure` defaults to `/usr/local` as prefix.

Comment: @StephenKitt Tell that to the Free/OpenBSD teams :-) 3rd-party software (i.e. things in the ports/package system) goes into `/usr/local` as they are local additions to the base system. NetBSD is better, using `/usr/pkg` instead.

Comment: @Kusalananda aargh! How long before some ports start using `/opt` or some other location? In fact `/opt` is used quite a bit in the Linux world by third-party packages... In the context of this question though `/usr/local` is safe (this is on Ubuntu).

Comment: @arod2028 The best way would be to use something like apt-offline to retrieve the .deb packages without an Internet connection.

Answer (score -3):

You may also need install these

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib 
sudo apt-get install -y git flex bison gperf build-essential libncurses5-dev:i386 
sudo apt-get install tofrodos python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc zlib1g-dev:i386 
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev libsdl1.2-dev libesd0-dev
sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential  
sudo apt-get install zip curl zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib 
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386 
sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev 
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc unzip m4
sudo apt-get install lib32z-dev ccache
```

Comment: Why on earth would the `m4` utility need all of that?

Comment: @Kusalananda I  really don't know why m4 is needed, i just install all this packages then it worked.

Comment: The user wants to use `m4`. _One_ of those packages is the `m4` package, the rest is just random.

Comment: What are you doing?

Comment: Are you being the annoying *bloated* `apt-get` that recommends its user to install unnecessary apps.